# Select only rows where two columns are both not null or zero within a partition

Tags: postgresql, select, multiple-columns, partition

I'm using PG 9.6.

I spent considerable time searching for a solution and couldn't find one. I came up with my own, but it seems like it could be done in a far more elegant way.

How do I select only rows within a partition defined by the combination of two columns (i.e. the combination of date and unique_id) that have at least four consecutive rows starting from rn 1 with no null or zero values in two columns var1 and var2? Thanks.

```
date     unique_id   var1   var2      rn
01-03-03 abc         .5       .4       1
01-03-03 abc         .3       .1       2
01-03-03 abc         .6       .3       3
01-03-03 abc         .4       .1       4
01-03-03 abc         .3       .3       5
01-03-03 abc         .7       .8       6
01-03-03 xyz         .4       .1       1
01-03-03 xyz         .6       .5       2
01-03-03 xyz         .5       .3       3
01-03-03 xyz         .3       null     4
01-03-03 xyz         .1       .2       5
01-03-03 xyz         .1       .9       6
01-03-03 efg         .2       .3       1
01-03-03 efg         .3       .8       2
01-03-03 efg         .4       .2       3
01-03-03 efg          0         0      4
01-03-03 efg          0         0      5
01-03-03 efg          0         0      6
01-03-03 lmn         .4       .1       1
01-03-03 lmn         .6       .5       2
01-03-03 lmn         .5       .3       3
01-03-03 lmn         .3       .9       4
01-03-03 lmn         null     null     5
01-03-03 lmn         null     null     6
```

Desired result of select:

```
date     unique_id   var1   var2      rn
01-03-03 abc         .5       .4       1
01-03-03 abc         .3       .1       2
01-03-03 abc         .6       .3       3
01-03-03 abc         .4       .1       4
01-03-03 abc         .3       .3       5
01-03-03 abc         .7       .8       6
01-03-03 lmn         .4       .1       1
01-03-03 lmn         .6       .5       2
01-03-03 lmn         .5       .3       3
01-03-03 lmn         .3       .9       4
```

Here's what I did (which works, but ugly):

```
SELECT *
FROM(

SELECT
unique_id,
date,
var1,
var2,

sum(c1) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id, date) as sum_c1,
sum(c2) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id, date) as sum_c2,
sum(c3) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id, date) as sum_c3



FROM

table1,

LATERAL (SELECT
            CASE
            WHEN rn <= 4 AND var1 IS NOT NULL AND var1 <> 0 AND var2 <> 0 AND 
            var2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END   as c1
    ) as test1,

LATERAL (SELECT
            CASE
            WHEN rn <= 5 AND var1 IS NOT NULL AND var1 <> 0 AND var2 <> 0 AND 
            var2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END   as c2
    ) as test2,

LATERAL (SELECT
            CASE
            WHEN rn <= 6 AND var1 IS NOT NULL AND var1 <> 0 AND var2 <> 0 AND 
            var2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END   as c1
    ) as test3

) t

WHERE
  sum_c1 = 4 AND var1 IS NOT NULL AND var1 <> 0 AND var2 <> 0 AND var2 IS NOT 
  NULL 
OR
  sum_c2 = 5 AND var1 IS NOT NULL AND var1 <> 0 AND var2 <> 0 AND var2 IS NOT 
  NULL 
OR
  sum_c3 = 6 AND var1 IS NOT NULL AND var1 <> 0 AND var2 <> 0 AND var2 IS NOT 
  NULL 

ORDER BY
date, unique_id, rn
```

Comment: My solution doesn't scale well. If rn can take the values 1 through 10 and I only still require 4 non null non zero rows, then there have to be 7 lateral selects, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 as t1
where not exists (
  select 1 from table1 as t2
  where
    t1.date = t2.date and
    t1.unique_id = t2.unique_id and
    t2.rn <= 4 and
    coalesce(t2.var1, 0) <> 0 and
    coalesce(t2.var2, 0) <> 0)
```

Comment: It seems so close, but it's returning all (I think all) the rows I don't want. I think I understand it. Selects everything in t1 where there is not a corresponding row in t2, where t2 is built by going row by row in t1 and selecting those rows where rn<=4 and var1 and var2 are not null and not zero. Except I want all the cases where there are at least 4 entries for var1 and 4 for var2 that are not null and not zero for rn = 1 to 4 consecutively plus all those cases where rn=1 to 5 consecutively with no nulls or zeros and where rn=1 to 6 consecutively with no nulls or zeros.

Comment: Tried changing 
coalesce(t2.var1, 0) <> 0 and coalesce(t2.var2, 0) <> 0)
to 
coalesce(t2.var1, 0) = 0 or coalesce(t2.var2, 0) = 0)
so it would grab the nulls or zeros but that resulted in an empty set. Also tried changing where not exists to where exists, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @JWells Sorry, I don't understand your requirements clearly. Does the requirement  "_where rn=1 to 5 consecutively with no nulls or zeros_" not included "_at least 4 entries for var1 and 4 for var2 that are not null and not zero for rn = 1 to 4 consecutively_"?

Comment: Sorry, that's because I didn't explain the requirements well. I need all the sets where both var1 and var2 are not null and not zero where rn=1 through 4, or rn=1 through 5, or rn =1 through 6. var1 and var2 go together, so having one be zero or null makes the pair not useful. In other words need at least 4 observations of the var1/var2 pair starting with rn (year) 1. But I also want those cases where there are 5 and 6 complete var1/var2 pairs.